# Code hints/Autocomplete - Aptana Studio/Eclipse

Tags: ee2

Working with Aptana Studio 3 (Windows & Mac). Does anyone know of a code hint bundle for EE? I know Coda has one and I like using it, but I am trying to get something that will work well for both environments, Mac/PC, for team use. Eclipse/Aptana Studio are pretty impressive, but would be great to have that for those not as familiar with commands. Would also make coding templates and add-ons quicker.

Comment: I am using the bundle [here](https://github.com/mrw/ExpressionEngine2-Sublime-Text-Bundle) from Matt and converting it to a ruble since it still doesn't jive with Windows versions completely. I'll post a link when I get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently (don't know for sure as I'm not an Aptana user) there is a command to convert Textmate bundle for use with Apatana. [Commands > Bundle Development > Convert Textmate Bundle](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/687-textmate-bundles#comment_3627297).

Update: It seems (based on the original poster's comment below) that this menu item is only available on the Mac version. If that option is available to you there are some good [EE Textmate bundles](http://eeinsider.com/blog/expressionengine-2-textmate-bundles/).

This doesn't answer your question but... you could switch to Sublime Text 2, which is cross-platform, uses Textmate bundles, and [has a good bundle here](https://github.com/mrw/ExpressionEngine2-Sublime-Text-Bundle).

Comment: Thanks Alex. Unfortunately, Aptana Studio 3 SAYS it has that option, but it is not in the DD Menu.

Comment: Yeah, that was a shot in the dark there. Hopefully someone else will have a better answer for you. And if you aren't married to Aptana Sublime Text _is_ great.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'll look at Sublime again. I had tried it a while back, but didn't stick with it for some reason. Maybe it will feel different this time around.  ;)

Comment: Ok Alex, I'm digging back into ST2 and I loaded the library from mrmartineau here: https://github.com/SublimeText/jQuery and mjareds EE lib here: https://github.com/imjared/ExpressionEngine2-Sublime-Text-Bundle but I still don't see good auto completion for jQuery and if I try to set Syntax to ExpressionEngine, it crashes. What libraries are you using with ST2?

Comment: I re-installed ST2 and the EE lib and it accepts it now, but I don't see code coloring or auto complete.   :(

Comment: Most color schemes require a small edit to get EE syntax highlighting. [See this answer](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/3671/22). You can also check out my modification of the Monokai Soda Theme https://github.com/twosixcode/Monokai-Soda-EE

Comment: The autocomplete comes in the form of "tab triggers." For jQuery the triggers are really intuitive, EE a bit less so. If you use the ST command palette (Cmd Shift P) and it will give you an idea what's available. Better yet you can browse the package contents (see the snippets).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I went through that and played around with it for a bit. It still seems that Aptana has a few features that the team I'll be working with would better benefit from on this project. 

I did figure out that the converter ONLY works with a Mac. I installed Aptana Studio on the Mac and was able to convert the tmBundle, then drop it in the windows install.

Comment: Ah, nice! Glad to hear that the converter worked.